# Textarea additional rows transition effect

Tags: textarea, row, transition

I have a code to add additional rows to my #moo textarea:

```
$('#moo').focus(function(){
    $(this).attr('rows', '4');
});
```

So when I focus the textarea gets higher. Is there any way to animate it? (css transition seems to fail this one).

Answer (score 0):

Use the height and transition css attributes.

```
textarea {
  height: 50px;
  transition: 1s
}

<textarea onclick="event.target.style.height=120px">
```